# Function not filling whole screen

Tags: react-native

Im trying to make an app for the weather in a certain place in the world given by lat and long. The thing is that when I check the screen the applicaction only shows like 1/5 in the center of the screen with the function executed to show the temperature.
Can't upload pictures because of my reputation. But imagine this is the screen: [----|||----] only the ||| portion shows.

I dont know much about react-native so im just searching and doing whatever somebody else do, i have tried forcing a view style "global" for the class but it seems itdoesnt work if you dont put it inside the render, return section which i cant move, atleast to the places i tried.

Didn't include the code inside the functions.

```
class WeatherScreen extends React.Component {
    state = {
        isLoading: true,
        temperature: 0,
        weatherCondition: null,
        error: null
    };
    componentDidMount() {
        ...
    } 
    fetchWeather(lat, lon) {
        fetch(....
    }


    render() {
    const { isLoading, weatherCondition, temperature } = this.state;
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            {isLoading ? (
                <View style={styles.loadingContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.loadingText}>Fetching The Weather</Text>
                </View>
            ) : (
                <Weather weather={weatherCondition} temperature={temperature}/>
            )}
        </View>
    );
  }
}
export default WeatherScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
});
```

Comment: give 100% height and width to your container.

Answer (score 0):

Do not apply `alignItems` and `justifyContent` to the main screen, it will bring your screen to center. If you want your content in the center then add these properties to **children View** of main container/View.
Also get screen width and height from react-native dimensions and add them to main container style(height, width).

Try this

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const height = Dimensions.get('window').height;

class YourClass extends Component {
...your code ...
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        height: height,
        width: width
    },
});
```

Comment: I tried it but it shows something like this 
[|||||||||||||||||||||||||]
[-------------------]
[-------------------]
it doesnt stack vertically, but imagine that is the phone, it only shows the top portion of the screen